# jQuery event target child element

Tags: jquery, events

Im trying to apply active class to child element and remove active class from parent element if child has mouseover event.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="section" style="width:500px">
    <div class="columns">Element 1</div>
    <div class="columns">Element 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is javascript code:

```
  $(".item").on({
      mouseover: function (event) {
          $(this).addClass("active");
          if($(event.target).is(".columns") && $(event.target).hasClass("active")) {
              $(".section", event.target).removeClass("active");
          } else {
              $(".section", event.target).addClass("active");
          }
      },

      mouseout: function () {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
      }
  }, '.section, .columns');
```

but I cant make is work.

1. When hover over columns elements, I need to add active class to it, but remove active class from section elements.
2. when hover section element add class active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery `.parent(".section")` would solve that issue and make your code more robust as it will be able to handle multiple sections independently without requiring extra code.

```js
$(".item").on({
  mouseover: function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(".columns")) {
      $(event.target).addClass("active");
      $(event.target).parent(".section").removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    };
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
}, '.section, .columns');
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.section{
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="columns">Element 1</div>
    <div class="columns">Element 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```